# firebase_admin auth delete_user suddenly not working as expected

Tags: firebase-authentication, firebase-admin

I have a piece of code that has run automatically twice a day for a very long time. At some point last week the auth.delete_user method I've always used began failing, and returning an error. Does anybody know what changed, or what I'm doing wrong? Nothing in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/python/firebase_admin.auth#delete_user) seems to have changed.

The error I'm getting back is:

```
Server response: {
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"local_id\": Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
    "errors": [
      {
        "message": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name \"local_id\": Proto field is not repeating, cannot start list.",
        "domain": "global",
        "reason": "badRequest"
      }
    ],
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

A contrived example of the code is:

```
from firebase_admin import credentials
from firebase_admin import auth
from firebase_admin import db

try:
    cred = credentials.Certificate("serviceAccountKey.json")
    firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
        'databaseURL': 'https://[project].firebaseio.com'
    })
except Exception as e:
    f.write(str(e.message))

uid = 'some valid UID string'
user = auth.delete_user(uid)
```

Any insight into what is going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The underlying implementation for this was actually incorrect.
This was [fixed a while back](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-admin-python/commit/ef397a0806a3a26a367cafd45788c233ee9d5d30#diff-1aff8f22529e59f0619e86c64e481048).

You should have received an email to upgrade your python admin sdk version.
Upgrading to the latest version should fix this.

Comment: Hey, thanks for pointing that out! I updated my local env but managed to forget to update the instances used for automation. Problem solved.